# How animation and transition styles cascade

Tags: css, css-animations, css-transitions

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Cascade#complete_cascade_order),
Cascade order looks like so:[image: Cascade order]
Where we can see transition styles take precedence over animation styles. But in my example it doesn't work so:

```css
div {
  width      : 200px;
  height     : 200px;
  background : red;
  animation  : rota 2s linear forwards infinite;
  transition : transform 40s linear;
  }
div:hover {
  background : green;
  transform  : translateX(1000px) !important;
  }
@keyframes rota {
  100% { transform: rotateZ(360deg); }
  }
```

```html
<div></div>
```

I expect the div to move slowly to the right on hover, because the transition styles should overwrite transform properties in the keyframe. But instead the behavior is very inconsistent, and animation styles more often take precedence, and transition styles not fully applied.

Comment: FWIW, Firefox seems to do what you expected. Chrome looks quite buggy, and Safari ... does its thing.

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? So that when hovering the block moves to the right and rotates?